# What Packages do I need to run a Python GUI program on Linux from the command line

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, beagleboneblack

I'm not sure where to start.

What do I need to run a Python GUI program on Linux from the command line? This will be on a BeagleBone Black. I want the BBB to boot into my program. The GUI will be very simple. It will have buttons for controlling a machine and labels to display data.

What packages do I need to install to support a GUI program? I don't want to run a full Desktop environment, I want everything to be as light as possible. What is the Python GUI toolkit would be good for this?

My OS is Ubuntu 13.04 command line only.

Comment: You can't have a GUI without (at least lightweight) desktop environment, e.g. xfce.

Comment: @J0HN This is absolutely [not true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer).

Comment: You may want to try pygtk running over framebuffer (not X11). Just install pygtk and the package manager will install all the dependencies. While it will install X11 and possibly a DE, you don't have to run them!

Comment: I have installed pygtk and have created a simple hello world program. But I get the following error "gtkwarning:could not open display". Are you sure pygtk can run on framebuffer?

Sorry for the late reply I was pulled away to work on other projects. I am just now trying to get back to this.

Comment: Although this is about PyQt instead of PyGTK, maybe this [thread suggesting the use of xvfb](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/PyQt-without-X11-tp1922488p1922492.html) is of any use for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using X11, you will have to run in linux framebuffer (fb). For that, you can choose between running just inside fb using for example fbpy (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fbpy/0.1) or if you want full GTK+, you will need GTK fb.

GTK fb version requires pango library, glib, gtk+ 2.0 or higher and FreeType. You can either build the gtk yourself or look for package such as gtk-linux-fb.